# O que significa "Já se foi"?

Tags: significado, português-brasileiro, significado-em-contexto

Gostaria de perguntar o que significa  "Já se foi", ou seja, qual é a diferença entre  "Já se foi" e  "Já foi"?

Eu sei que usamos "se" quando o sujeito não é claro ou não importa quem é. Mas no exemplo de baixo a situação é diferente:

> A lebre é rápida demais.  Já se foi!

O sujeito é claro. Por que não é

> A lebre é rápida, Já foi.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O "se" aqui não constrói o passivo, mas sim dá ao verbo "ir" um novo [significado](https://dicionario.priberam.org/ir):

> **verbo pronominal**
> 16. Desaparecer, gastar-se (ex.: *o salário foi-se; a minha paciência vai-se rápido*).
> 17. Deixar de funcionar (ex.: *o telemóvel foi-se*). = AVARIAR

Assim, em

> A lebre é rápida demais. Já se foi!

entende-se que ela "Já sumiu!", "Já desapareceu!", enquanto em

> A lebre é rápida demais. Já foi!

parece que "Já partiu", "Já foi embora.".

Comment: Acrescento como referência um uso no seriado Chaves: [Já se foi o disco voador!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uLvLpSwFvik)

Answer (score 1):

O "se" em "já se foi" acrescenta uma idéia de que o sujeito já está longe, em termos de **distância** ou de **tempo**.
"A lebre já foi" significa apenas que já foi embora. Incluindo a partícula "se", soma-se a idéia de que partiu rápido, ou que já partiu há algum tempo ou há muito tempo.

"Já se foram os dias em que as crianças queriam apenas brinquedos no Natal.  Hoje em dia..."

mas...

"**Já se foi o tempo** em que algumas doenças eram tratadas com a aplicação de ventosas." não é muito diferente de "**já foi tempo em que**..." (assim mesmo, sem o artigo definido) e ambas as formas são idiomáticas.

No entanto, **contexto e entonação** podem fazer com que ambas as formas (*já foi* e *já se foi*) tenham exatamente o mesmo significado.

Answer (score 0):

significa alguém que já saiu ou que já partiu de um determinado lugar; ou também para expressar alguém que faleceu.

Answer (score -1):

O significado deste termo se refere claramente a algo que ''acabou de sair do lugar onde estava'' ou ''foi embora''.